# (prestashop) What is AdminController::$currentIndex for?

Tags: controller, admin, prestashop

I was simply wandering what's the purpose of AdminController::$currentIndex in prestahop. I took a look to the relevant classes but can't really figure it out.

Does anyone know?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the url of the current page. You can see how it is set in AdminController::init()